# SVG not working with webpack 2 and url loader

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I can't make work svg-s with webpack 2. When bundle gets compiled I get a warning and when I load the page the svg-s are not showing up. I am guessing my webpack 2 config is working (although it's quite a mess at the moment) since png-s and jpg-s are properly loaded.

Error:

```
WARNING in ./src/assets/wheels/19.svg
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)   resolve-url-loader 
 cannot operate: CSS error
 /Users/asilo/Desktop/js/react/react-tesla-range-
 calculator/src/assets/wheels/19.svg:1:83: missing '{'
 at error (/Users/silo/Desktop/js/react/react-tesla-range-
 calculator/node_modules/css/lib/parse/index.js:62:15)
```

src/components/TeslaWheels/TeslaWheels.js

```
import './TeslaWheels.css';
.......
<label className="tesla-wheels__item tesla-wheels__item--19"
```

src/componentes/TeslaWheels/TeslaWheels.css

```
.tesla-wheels__item--19 {
  background-image: url(../../assets/wheels/19.svg);
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
  path: __dirname,
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use : [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-1']
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'style-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
          options: {
            query: {
              classPrefix: true,
              idPrefix: true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          options: {
            query: {
              publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            query: {
              limit: 10000,
              mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      use: [
        'file-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            query: {
              publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
              useRelativePath: true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          options: {
            query: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
              optiping: {
                optimizationLevel: 7
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: true,
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Comment: is assets folder inside src folder? please check it once.

Comment: Yeah assets is within src. Png-s are also there and those are loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

use svg-url-loader . It will solve your issue. I had the same issue , I debugged and found that url-loader is corrupt data uri for svg , I don't know why .
But svg-url-loader solved my issue.
Use of svg-url-loader with  below config will solve the issue :

{
test: /.svg/,
use: {
loader: 'svg-url-loader',
options: {
limit: 10000000
}
}
},